# SQL Pivot & Union Troubles in Pervasive

Tags: sql, pivot, union, pervasive

I'm rather inexperienced with sql, but I know I need a combination of pivot & union on my table to get a result set I can work with. Any help is appreciated, but what I'm trying to achieve is for any given month, list out hours worked per week for each employee.

Actual Table:

```
Employee         Date          Hours_Worked

John             141201        10
John             141210        15
John             141220        20
Jane             141203        25
Jane             141206        10
```

Desired Table:

```
Employee          Wk1          Wk2          Wk3          Wk4          Wk5

John              10           15           20           0            0
Jane              35           0            0            0            0
```

And probably worth noting; the date column is a char(6) datatype.

What I've been doing right now is having multiple queries, one for each week, like this:

```
SELECT employee, sum(hours_worked) as wk1 FROM job_detail WHERE date_sequence BETWEEN '141200' AND '141208' GROUP BY employee;
```

But this is only taking me part of the way because I'm getting a row for each one, even if they have the same employee, which is where I thought about union, but then ideally the results need to be in a column for 1 row per employee, which is where I thought about pivot.

Comment: I'd say the biggest hurdle is interpreting the date numbers. If you can convert those to week numbers, then you're almost home free. As such, however, your question is a bit too broad.

Comment: In my head I was hoping I could do something like....  

BETWEEN 'x' and 'y' as wk1  

And I'm using PHP to handle the data. As of now, I'm doing multiple queries...where one has a different date range to give me the results for that week, but I then realized I could probably combine them into one query and use pivot to put them as I need them.  

@DaaaahWhoosh

Comment: How far out are you wanting to go? Wk6,7,8,9,10+??

Comment: you said as of right now you're doing multiple queries. POST THEM PLEASE!

Comment: @Matt

I should have been more clear, but I was only looking to do the weeks of a given month, so 5 max. My example is showing December.

Comment: @Jt2ouan

One of my queries looks like this:  

SELECT employee, sum(hours_worked) as wk1 FROM job_detail WHERE date_sequence BETWEEN '141200' AND '141208' GROUP BY employee;

Comment: I know how to do this in t-sql. Can you do sum(case....when...end) in pervasive?

Comment: @Matt  

Yes, it appears I can do case/when/end in the version Pervasive I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with. The day numbers might need to be adjusted. I'm sure there is probably a date/week function, just not familiar with pervasive.

```
select 
    employee,

    SUM(case when RIGHT(date,2) between 0 and 7 then hours_worked else 0 end) as wk1,
    SUM(case when RIGHT(date,2) between 8 and 15 then hours_worked else 0 end) as wk2,
    SUM(case when RIGHT(date,2) between 16 and 21 then hours_worked else 0 end) as wk3,
    SUM(case when RIGHT(date,2) between 22 and 29 then hours_worked else 0 end) as wk4,
    SUM(case when RIGHT(date,2) between 30 and 31 then hours_worked else 0 end) as wk5
from #t
group by employee
```

Output:

```
employee             wk1         wk2         wk3         wk4         wk5
-------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
Jane                 35          0           0           0           0
John                 10          15          20          0           0
```

Comment: Thank you!! This works exactly as I needed to, and didn't use pivot/union like I anticipated. I'm gonna have to read more about case/then/end, but thank you so much. Major headache gone.